# How can I open an FTP server using cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I wonder how can I do that using cmd, which I presume is the fastest way possible.

Comment: The versions of Windows I used had a very crude ftp client built in, just type ftp Site.name. - but don't assume the client is fast or any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I open an FTP server using cmd?

```
ftp host
```

where `host` is Host name or IP address of the remote host.

```
ftp /?

Transfers files to and from a computer running an FTP server service
(sometimes called a daemon). Ftp can be used interactively.

FTP [-v] [-d] [-i] [-n] [-g] [-s:filename] [-a] [-A] [-x:sendbuffer] [-r:recvbuffer] [-b:asyncbuffers] [-w:windowsize] [host]

  -v              Suppresses display of remote server responses.
  -n              Suppresses auto-login upon initial connection.
  -i              Turns off interactive prompting during multiple file
                  transfers.
  -d              Enables debugging.
  -g              Disables filename globbing (see GLOB command).
  -s:filename     Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the
                  commands will automatically run after FTP starts.
  -a              Use any local interface when binding data connection.
  -A              login as anonymous.
  -x:send sockbuf Overrides the default SO_SNDBUF size of 8192.
  -r:recv sockbuf Overrides the default SO_RCVBUF size of 8192.
  -b:async count  Overrides the default async count of 3
  -w:windowsize   Overrides the default transfer buffer size of 65535.
  host            Specifies the host name or IP address of the remote
                  host to connect to.

Notes:
  - mget and mput commands take y/n/q for yes/no/quit.
  - Use Control-C to abort commands.
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [ftp](https://ss64.com/nt/ftp.html) - File Transfer Protocol. (Not Secure, for Secure FTP utilities see the links page.